# How to download data from Yahoo finance limited to 100 rows

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, powerquery, import-from-csv

So I'm doing this project where I have to download historical stock data from yahoo finance. Got this code. It's working fine, BUT it only downloads max 100 rows. I tried to scan the web for answers or a different code (this one is just recorded macro from excel) but I saw a few tutorials on YouTube that use his solution and it's just fine.

.. I don't understand it then

```
Sub Makro6()

    ' Dowload stock prices from Yahoo Finance based on input

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    'clear previous queries
    For Each qr In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        qr.Delete
    Next qr

    'clear Data sheet
    ws.Select
    Cells.Clear

    'clear graphs
    'ws.ChartObjects.Delete

    'stock = Sheets("Main").Range("A2")

    StartDate = toUnix(Sheets("Main").Range("A4"))
    EndDate = toUnix(Sheets("Main").Range("A6"))

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2 (3)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Zdroj = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & stock & "/history?period1=" & StartDate & "&period2=" & EndDate & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Zdroj{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Změněný typ"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type text}, {""High"", type text}, {""Low"", type text}, {""Close*"", type tex" & _
        "t}, {""Adj Close**"", type text}, {""Volume"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Změněný typ"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 2 (3)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 2 (3)]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_2_3"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Data").Select

    '' Sort data by date from oldest to newest

    ws.ListObjects("Table_2_3").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ws.ListObjects("Table_2_3").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add2 Key:=Range("A1:A99"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.ListObjects("Table_2_3").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Call DeleteDividends

    Call Stochastics


End Sub
```

The code works for other websites. I tried to download Wikipedia page list of total 120 and it loaded data no problem.

The problem is the data from Yahoo finance website is a project requirement

Comment: You may be rate-limited by the site.

Comment: What about trying to use the download query to capture the data in a CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check against the page you will discover only 100 results are initially present within the `HTMLTable` rows (`tbody` to be precise).

Enter the css selector `[data-test="historical-prices"] tbody tr` in the browser elements tab search box (<kbd>F12</kbd> to open dev tools)and you will see this:

[image]

The rest of the rows are fed dynamically from a data store as you scroll down the page. Of course, your current method doesn't pick up on these. You can in fact issue an xhr request, regex out the appropriate javascript object housing all the rows, and parse with a json parser.

Here is roughly what you should currently see in response:

[image]

I use  jsonconverter.bas as my json parser.  Download raw code from [here](http://%20https//github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called `jsonConverter` . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

@TimWilliams wrote a better unix conversion function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12326121/6241235) but I thought I would have a play at writing something different. I would advise you to stick with his as it is safer and faster.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub GetYahooData()
    '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object, re As Object, s As String, xhr As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim startDate As String, endDate As String, stock As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    stock = "AAPL"
    startDate = "1534809600" 
    endDate = "1566345600"     

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & stock & "/history?period1=" & startDate & "&period2=" & endDate & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&_guc_consent_skip=" & GetCurrentUnix(Now()), False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With

    s = GetJsonString(re, s)
    If s = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
    WriteOutResults ws, json
End Sub

Public Sub WriteOutResults(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal json As Object)
    Dim item As Object, key As Variant, headers(), results(), r As Long, c As Long

    headers = json.item(1).keys
    ReDim results(1 To json.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For Each item In json
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        For Each key In item.keys
            results(r, c) = item(key)
            c = c + 1
        Next
    Next
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With      
End Sub

Public Function GetJsonString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal responseText As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "HistoricalPriceStore"":{""prices"":(.*?\])" 'regex pattern to get json string
        If .test(responseText) Then
            GetJsonString = .Execute(responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetJsonString = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetCurrentUnix(ByVal t As Double) As String
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .parentWindow.execScript "function GetTimeStamp(t){return new Date(t).getTime() / 1000}", "jscript"
        GetCurrentUnix = .parentWindow.GetTimeStamp(Now)
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Regex:**

[image]

---

**Python:**

I initially wrote as python if of interest:

```
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

p = re.compile('HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":(.*?\])')
r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1534809600&period2=1566345600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&_guc_consent_skip=1566859607')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do functions `GetCurrentUnix` and `GetTimeStamp` accept an argument? Were they originally written for some other purpose? Interesting approach and answer.

Comment: @chillin GetCurrentUnix has an argument because when using javascript in this way I have to rely on native methods and with my limited js passing in an existing date in this way allowed me to leverage Date(t).getTime() - in built javascript. Other libraries/APIs can't be accessed.

Comment: It is not the most efficient way but I wanted to explore what was possible via this method having used if for url encoding/decoding before.

Comment: I don't want to belabour the point as my comment is tangential/off-topic. I was just expecting function to be `Public Function GetCurrentUnix() As String` and the JavaScript function to be `function GetTimeStamp(){return new Date().getTime() / 1000}`. Saves having to pass around `t` (unless the function was originally for converting any date time `t` to a Unix timestamp and not just `Now`). Your method was new to me, thanks.

Comment: I remember now... I did try that originally. What I see happening is that the function then returns the function definition as opposed to the timestamp. However, you can completely remove as you show above but so long as  .parentWindow.GetTimeStamp() has a param e.g.  .parentWindow.GetTimeStamp(1) then it will correctly return. I found that confusing and kept with clear parameterization.