# Excel VBA - Web Scraping - Inner Text of HTML Table Cell

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to build a macro to web scrape the status of a Cargo Shipment based on the shipment number.
I am using the XML-HTTP method but I am new to VBA web scraping.
I have tried to get the value by using the GetValuebyID,Tag, Class with no success.

The highlighted line is the one I need the value extracted from.
[Need to Extract the 10 of 10 Delivered Value][1]

This is how far I have gotten with the code.

```
Sub FlightStat()

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim AllTables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim MainTable As IHTMLTable


XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://www.unitedcargo.com/OurNetwork/TrackingCargo1512/Tracking.jsp?id=10205436&pfx=016", False

XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

Set AllTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagID("dispTable0")

  

End Sub
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me get the "10 of 10 Delivered" value extracted
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcOAZ.png

Comment: When you say "**with no success**", it doesn't tell us anything. Please explain what happens when you run your code.. is there an error thrown? if so, what is the error? if not, what happens?

Comment: The table you need will be load as dynamic content. So you can't use xhr (as far as I know) But you can do it with the IE. You must wait to load the dynamic content after the IE reports page load is complete. Furthermore there is no method called `getElementsByTagID()`. What you want is `getElementByID()`.

Comment: @Zac, Sorry for that. That was a typo. I was trying to type ByTag, ByID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, like I wrote in my comment. You can scrape the status with the IE.

**Please note:** The following code has no timeout built in if the dynamic content cannot be loaded. There is also no check whether the number passed in the URL is correct.

```
Sub FlightStat()

Dim url As String
Dim ie As Object
Dim nodeTable As Object

  'You can handle the parameters id and pfx in a loop to scrape dynamic numbers
  url = "https://www.unitedcargo.com/OurNetwork/TrackingCargo1512/Tracking.jsp?id=10205436&pfx=016"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = False
  ie.navigate url
  Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  'Wait to load dynamic content after IE reports it's ready
  'We can do that in a loop to match the point the information is available
  Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nodeTable = ie.document.getElementByID("dispTable0")
    On Error GoTo 0
  Loop Until Not nodeTable Is Nothing
  
  'Get the status from the table
  MsgBox Trim(nodeTable.getElementsByTagName("li")(2).innertext)
  
  'Clean up
  ie.Quit
  Set ie = Nothing
  Set nodeTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do it with xmlhttp. You just need the right endpoint to query. As it returns json you really should use a json parser, or Instr/InstrRev (for small simple string extraction). However, as I didn't want to import an external dependency (other than ticking the add reference in VBE), and the response format is standard, I went with regex. The 10 of 10 is calculated as the number of items delivered over the number of items received (start and end `pieces`), along with the first `statusDescription`; the latest tracking info always comes first in the string.

This will be much quicker than using a browser.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FlightStat()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp 'required reference Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
    
    Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    
    With XMLReq
    
        .Open "GET", "https://www.unitedcargo.com/TrackingServlet?BranchCode=&CompanyName=Test&DocumentNumbers=016-10205436&UserName=&_=" & toUnix(Now()), False
        .send

        If .status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & .status & " - " & .statusText
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        Dim s As String, output As String, matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
        
        s = .responseText
        
    End With

    With re
    
        .Pattern = """Pieces"":""(.*?)"""
        .Global = True
        
        Set matches = .Execute(s)
        
        Dim status As String
        
        .Pattern = "StatusDescription"":""(.*?)"""
        .Global = False
        status = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
        output = matches.Item(0).SubMatches(0) & " of " & matches.Item(matches.Count - 1).SubMatches(0) & Chr$(32) & status
        
        Debug.Print output
        
    End With
End Sub

Public Function toUnix(ByVal dt As Variant) As Long
    '@TimWilliams https://stackoverflow.com/a/12326121
    toUnix = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", dt)
End Function
```