# Table scraping Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need help scraping the  tags onto my excel from an internal company website.

This is the source code.

```html
<br />
<span class="RptTitle"><input id="chkPromisDataLog" type="checkbox" name="chkPromisDataLog" checked="checked" onclick="showOnOffPromisLog();" /><label for="chkPromisDataLog">Promis Processing data log [83508442.1].</label></span>
<div id="divPromisDataLog" style="display: none;">
    <table id="tblPromisDataLog" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td width="60%"></td>
            <td>
                <a class="textnormal" href="javascript:popwnd=window.open('../Tools/ExportExcel.aspx?KEY=LOT_GEN_PROMIS','popwnd','status=no,toolbar=Yes,menubar=Yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=Yes');popwnd.focus()">
                    Export to Excel
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="dgPromisDataLog" style="border-color: Black; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr class="rptDetailsHeaderMgt" align="center">
                        <td>LotID</td>
                        <td>Hist Stage</td>
                        <td>Datein</td>
                        <td>Dateout</td>
                        <td>Qtyin</td>
                        <td>Qtyout</td>
                        <td>M/C ID</td>
                        <td>Emp TrackOut</td>
                        <td>Hold Code</td>
                        <td>Hold Reason</td>
                        <td>Staging (Hrs)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="rptDetailsItemMgt" align="center" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <td>83508442.1</td>
                        <td>
                            <a
                                href="javascript:popwnd=window.open('LotGen_Dtl.aspx?iDate=04/09/2021 09:07:07 PM&amp;amp;oDate=04/10/2021 03:47:59 PM&amp;amp;oLotid=83508442.1&amp;amp;oStage=C-WFRPROCS&amp;amp;oLastRow=N','popwnd','width=900,height=600,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,top=100,right=50,left=50');popwnd.focus();"
                            >
                                C-WFRPROCS
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>4/9/2021 9:07:07 PM</td>
                        <td>4/10/2021 3:47:59 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>10911700</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>18.68</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is roughly my code

```
Sub Lotsearch()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer 'start new IE page
    ie.Visible = True 'View what is happening in IE
    ie.navigate "www.internalcompanywebsite.aspx" 'Open link in IE
    
    While ie.readyState <> 4 'Waits for IE to finish loading
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
        i = 1
    
    'ie.document.getElementById("tblPromisDataLog") = Cells(2, 1).Value
    
    'ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td").Value = Cells(5, 1).Value
    
    'Set Data = ie.document.getElementByTagName("rptDetailsItemMgt")
    'Dim myValue As String
    'myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(0).innerHTML
    
    'Cells(3, 13) = myValue
    'Range("L1").Value = myValue

    'For Each htmlEle In ie.document.getElementById("tblPromisDataLog")(0).getElementsByClassName("rptDetailsItemMgt")

        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
        '    .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
        '    .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
        '    .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
        '    .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
        '    .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
        '    .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
        '    .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(7).textContent
        '    .Range("I" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(8).textContent
        '    .Range("J" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(9).textContent
        '    .Range("K" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(10).textContent
        '    .Range("L" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(11).textContent
            
        End With
        
        i = i + 1
    
    Next htmlEle
        
    ie.Quit

    
End Sub
```

As you can see, I have tried various methods but to no avail.

getElementbyID not working

getElementsbyTagName not working

getElementsByClassName not working

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel just use a well worn library. You can join a group of people here who are all trying to do the same thing: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - Web Scraping - Inner Text of HTML Table Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738093/excel-vba-web-scraping-inner-text-of-html-table-cell)

Comment: What is the desired output format and values?

Comment: getElementById returns a single node so there is no indexing i.e. no (0)

Comment: 83508442.1
C-WFRPROCS
4/9/2021 9:07:07 PM
4/10/2021 3:47:59 PM
0
9
10911700
18.68
I want the output like this as in a table format. I just realised that I should use "dgPromisDataLog" for my getElementbyId ?

Answer (score 1):

it may not actually be the most efficient way to deal with HTML extraction, but you might consider using Regex matching.. Raw Coding on youtube just made a killer regex tutorial, and I remembered seeing this question, and thought it might be a good alternative if you didn't like dealing with html explicitly.

[Regex Tutorial for Beginners from Raw Coding on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s32PyN3q2gY)

like, if you only wanted normal text between td tags, you could regex search for

```
(?<OpenTag>[\<]+td[\>]+)(?<Contents>[\w\/\(\)\[\]\.\&\:\;\s]*?)(?<CloseTag>[\<]+[\/]+[td]+[\>]+)
```

here's an example at Regex101

[Regex101 example using your html](https://regex101.com/r/NlzIMZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ht As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Integer
Dim htmltable As MSHTML.htmltable

Set htmltable = ht.getElementById("dgPromisDataLog")
    
    myValue = htmltable.getElementsByClassName("rptDetailsItemMgt")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
```

After messing with it for a few days, I found that the code works if I split up the getElementbyId from the other 'getElements'.

Changed htmlEle As IHTMLElement into ht As HTMLDocument. Also added htmltable As MSHTML.htmltable

For some reason the code returns an error if I chain the entire 'getelement' together. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.