# csv export from tradingview change the time format to readable time format

Tags: excel

I downloaded the data from tradingview which was exported csv format but the time format is unreadable. please see below.

```
1502942400
1502949600
1502956800
1502964000
1502971200
1502978400
1502985600
1502992800
1503000000
```

How can I change it to yyyy / mm / dd  hh : mm format by excel ?

Grateful if you advise. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unix time stamps represent the number of seconds since `1 Jan 1970`.

Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of a day since `1 Jan 1900`.

There are `86400` seconds in a day (`24*60*60`)

So to convert:

```
=A1/86400+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

and format the result as you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are in unix time format.

so just use this function on each number
put this function in a module .

```
Public Function fromUnix(ts) As String
    fromUnix = Format(DateAdd("s", ts, "1/1/1970 00:00:00"), "yyyy / mm / dd mm:hh")
End Function
```

and use it like

```
=fromUnix ("1502949600") OR =fromUnix (Range("A1").value) ' or whatever cell.
```

credits >> [the source for this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325948/excel-vba-convert-a-date-string-to-a-unix-timestamp/12326121)